# Unable to intercept request/response body in Playwright while web-scraping

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, playwright-python

Have the task to parse this page: **https://privatleasing.volkswagen.se/valjmodell** .I will need to get **models** and **prices** for leasing by entering each model's page and getting the data.

First problem is that this website works in my country **only under VPN**.

I started from trying to use simple instruments like "requests"/"Beautifulsoup" - doesn't work because website use JavaScript almost for everything.

Then tried to find hidden API - there is API which gets JSON including the list of links for each model page.
Here is the full link of API(numbers are changing): https://nosp-api.vwfs-se-nosp.vwfs.io/api/category?nocache=1690533980259

Here is screenshot of inspector:
[Inspector screenshot with required data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNNcE.png)
This data would be usefull for a start. I can see this JSON in inspector, but cannot have direct access. Tried to pass all headers from "request headers" - returns error 403.

Then tried to use Playwright as shown in this article: https://www.zenrows.com/blog/web-scraping-intercepting-xhr-requests#use-case-auctioncom
As a result I can get all links of requests and responses. I can filter them to get only those which contain JSON - but there is no such JSON as shown on the screenshot.
I have thoughts that it's all because of VPN issue - I'm not sure that Chromium browser in Playwright loads the page.
Also I'm still new to scraping and Playwright, so couldn't understand if it is possible to scrape that page at all.

Despite Playwright I also tried to use Selenium, but again faced the VPN issue. Tried to make Selenium Chrome browser use my account which has VPN add-on always turned-on. This didn't work out - the start page freezes and nothing happens.

Also I tried to use proxy-servers both for Selenium and Playwright variants. I used free servers for testing as the project is not so serious to pay for proxy yet. Anyway Both Selenium and Plywright able to load the page (if proxy works), but the speed is so slow that it will not be possible to jump prom page to page and get data - I think this variant is too unstable.

Here is how my code looks like right now:

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

def test_json(response):
    try:
        print(response.json())
    except:
        pass

with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=False)
    page = browser.new_page()

    page.on("request", lambda request: test_json(request))
    page.on("response", lambda response: test_json(response))

    page.goto("https://privatleasing.volkswagen.se/valjmodell", wait_until='networkidle')
    page.context.close()
    browser.close()
```

If it matters the whole project is done in scrapy framework but with this website I do tests outside scrapy for now.

Will be happy to hear your suggestions on what I do wrong and if it is possible to parse this website at all?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was found - desktop VPN application solves the problem.
Now when using the code I mentioned the required JSON appeared in the list of results.
Hope this will help someone)